# Array stores 2 values in one "place"

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

When I start my program I cannot insert only one number as "number 1" but two.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    int array[5] = {};
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        printf("Insert number %d \n", i+1);
        scanf("%d%", &array[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }

    printf("Sum is %d \n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Im new to C(switching from C++).

Comment: I recommend compiling with the `-Werror` flag, which turns compiler warnings into compiler errors. A lot of unexpected behavior can occur in C if you ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: It might also help you in the long-run to use proper indentation so that it's harder to get confused on which closing brackets `}` close what.

Comment: @Wamadeahama and `-Wall` and `-Wextra` to actually get diagnostics...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the second % in

```
scanf("%d%", &array[i]);
```

to be

```
scanf("%d", &array[i]);
```